# Problema al descargar .xlsx en Chrome Error: error red

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, google-chrome

Cuando quiero exportar una lista de tipo IEnumerable desde Chrome me da un error que dice "Error: error de red". Lo pruebo en Firefox y anda bien, descarga el archivo. Alguien sabrá como solucionar esto, o tiene una alternativa (otro método para descargar el xls?)

```
 private void ExportXls(IEnumerable list, string NameFile)
        {
            var workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(new Worksheet("Datos"));
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            var ws = worksheet;

            ws.GenerateByIEnumerable(list);





            HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + NameFile + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx" + "\"");
            workbook.Save(response.OutputStream);
            response.Flush();
            response.Close();
            response.End();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver sacando el `response.Close()` y cambiando el  `response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` por `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`;

```
private void ExportXls(IEnumerable list, string NameFile)
        {
            var workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(new Worksheet("Datos"));
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            var ws = worksheet;

            ws.GenerateByIEnumerable(list);





            HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + NameFile + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx" + "\"");
            workbook.Save(response.OutputStream);
            response.Flush();
           // response.Close();
            response.End();
        }
```